# VeeValidate not working with inline editing. I am using v-for and v-if for inline editing

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I have user list inline editing table structure. Each row is represents a user. I am editing user and using vee validate for validation

```js
validateState(ref) {
    if (
      this.veeFields[ref] &&
      (this.veeFields[ref].dirty || this.veeFields[ref].validated)
    ) {
      return !this.veeErrors.has(ref)
    }
    return null
  },

  saveUserUpdate: function(user) {
    this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
      debugger
      if (!result) {
        return
      } else {
        //code to save user api
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<tr v-for="(user, userIndex) in userList" :key="userIndex">
  <td>
    <span v-show="user.isEditing">
   <b-form-input size="sm" v-model="user.fullName" :name="'tbnewFullName' + user.unique_id" :state="validateState('tbnewFullName' + userIndex)" :aria-describedby="'tbnewFullName-feedback' + userIndex"></b-form-input>
   <b-form-invalid-feedback :id="'tbnewFullName-feedback' + userIndex">
    Required.
   </b-form-invalid-feedback>
  </span>
    <div v-show="!user.isEditing">
      {{user.fullName}}
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing here but validations are not fired in `saveUserUpdate`. veeFields list in validateState are not showing my user's name field. Also veeFields is showing list of fields from previous form.

Comment: Where is `saveUserUpdate` being called?

Comment: on inline save button for every row

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `v-model="userList[userIndex].fullName`.  See [here](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1851) for details.  The summary is, due to how vee-validate works internally, they have trouble tracking the limited-in-scope `user` variable.